# express.js app get not showing console log message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, console.log

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("started at 3000");
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

  console.log("Hello");

  const car = "read";

  res.send("Hello, world");

});
```

res.send is working fine. However, console log is not showing. It only shows when I remove the variable.

I am running using nodemon.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: For me, its working fine, with node.js when running node

Comment: I am facing the same problem too. Have you noticed the culprit?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Nodemon with Auto Save cause the problem, use manual save (Ctrl + S) instead

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine. As good practice. Always put app.listen as the last code in index (entry) file.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    console.log("Hello");
  
    const car = "read";
  
    res.send("Hello, world");
  
  });

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("started at 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

it works perfectly fine,just to confirm things add app.listen() to the bottom of code.

1. after running `nodemon app.js`
2. open browser-> `visit localhost:3000`, you will see the hello in your console/cmd/terminal

**Reason** :- **The below mentioned code literally means when a GET request is send to this path i.e "/" then, in the console print "Hello", and as a response to that GET request, send "Hello,World"**

```
const port =3000||port.env.PORT

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

  console.log("Hello");

  const car = "read";

  res.send("Hello, world");

});
    app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("started at "+port);
});
```

*Sometimes nodemon can be a little wacky or late to take in the updates,in such situations, therefore, try stopping the server and rerun it using the nodemon command*

Comment: Following the steps you provided fix the issue, but after I make some changes on the console log string it wont work again. Restarting nodemon doesn't fix the issue, I have tried regular node command as well, didn't work.
On second try following the steps, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can you post your "changes" which you did  to console.log let me check

Comment: I found the problem, it was because of auto save. Everything is normal again using manual save.

Comment: Use shortcut "ctrl-s", wont fall into that problem again,if it helped you, please accept it as answer to your problem, so that it may help others in the future:)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postman to send your GET request, the console.log() should show up in the console in vscode or wherever you run your express server from, it will not display in Postman as part of the api response. For your console to log correctly you need to restart your server every time you change your files, so you say you use Nodemon for that. Maybe try stopping and restarting your project again manually? Are you looking for the console.log to display in the right place?

Comment: I have stop and restarting it but not working. Just want to have the console log displayed on the terminal. Regular node command also not working.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem in your code it's absolutely right

you can see the `console.log("hello")` in the cmd

when you run the `localhost:3000` in your browser you can see it at cmd after 'started at 3000'